# Did King Achashverosh wear the Kohen Gadol clothing?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, purim, megillat-esther, kohen-gadol

I have heard about King Achashverosh having the kelim from the beis hamikdash at his feast.

I am looking for more information regarding Achashverosh wearing the clothing of the kohen gadol at his feast, i saw it mentioned [Gemara Megillah 12a](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.12a.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%B4%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%90%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%AA%D7%95%D6%B9%20%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%AA%20%D7%A2%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B6%D7%A8%20%D7%9B%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%91%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%93%20%D7%9E%D6%B7%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%9B%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%AA%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%B4%2C%20%D7%90%D6%B8%D7%9E%D6%B7%D7%A8%20%D7%A8%D6%B7%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%99%20%D7%99%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%A1%D6%B5%D7%99%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%A8%20%D7%97%D6%B2%D7%A0%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%A0%D6%B8%D7%90%3A%20%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%9C%D6%B7%D7%9E%D6%BC%D6%B5%D7%93%20%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B6%D7%9C%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%91%D6%B7%D7%A9%D7%81%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%92%D6%B0%D7%93%D6%B5%D7%99%20%D7%9B%D6%B0%D7%94%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%A0%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%94.%20%D7%9B%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%91%20%D7%94%D6%B8%D7%9B%D6%B8%D7%90%3A%20%D7%B4%D7%99%D6%B0%D7%A7%D6%B8%D7%A8%20%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%A4%D6%B0%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%A8%D6%B6%D7%AA%20%D7%92%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%93%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%9C%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%AA%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%B4%2C%20%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%9B%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%91%20%D7%94%D6%B8%D7%AA%D6%B8%D7%9D%3A%20%D7%B4%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%9B%D6%B8%D7%91%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%93%20%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%B4%D7%A4%D6%B0%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%A8%D6%B6%D7%AA%D7%B4.) and [Midrash Lekach Tov](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Lekach_Tov_on_Esther.1.7.4?lang=bi#:%7E:text=%D7%A1%22%D7%90%20%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D.%20%D7%94%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99%20%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%9D%2C%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9%2C%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9%20%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%3A), as well as here [Pri Etz Chaim Here](https://www.sefaria.org/Pri_Etz_Chaim%2C_Gate_of_The_New_Month%2C_Chanukah%2C_and_Purim.6.36?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%9B%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%20%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%20%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%AA%20%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95%2C%20%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%92%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F%20%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%2C%20%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%98%20%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%9F%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%93%20%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9C%2C%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%9D%20%D7%A2%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%A9%3A) which makes the connection with the bigdei kehuna, but id like to find more sources for this, as well as knowing specifically which bigdei kehuna he had and was wearing.

(If you enjoy this question and discussion, please up-vote)

Answer (score 1):

It says similarly in the [Ein Yaakov](https://www.sefaria.org/Ein_Yaakov_(Glick_Edition)%2C_Megillah.1.19?vhe=En_Jacob,_translated_by_SH_Glick,_1916&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) on the Gemara;

> בהראותו את עשר כבוד מלכותו ואת יקר וגומר אמר רבי יוסי ברבי חנינא מלמד שלבש בגדי כהונה ונתעטף ועמד כתיב הכא את יקר תפארת גדולתו וכתיב התם (שמות כח ב) לכבוד ולתפארת. ובמלאת הימים האלה וגומר רב ושמואל חד אמר מלך פקח היה וחד אמר טפש היה למאן דאמר פקח היה שפיר עביד דקריב רחיקי ברישא דבני מאתיה כל אימת דבעי להו מקרב להו ומאן דאמר טפש היה בני מאתיה איבעי ברישא לקרובי דאי מרדו הנך הני הוו קיימי בהדיה
>
> When he showed the riches and the glory of his kingdom, etc. R. Jose, the son of R. Chanina, said: "You can infer from this that Ahasuerus attired himself in the priestly garments and stood with his guest, for it is written here, And the glory of his greatness, and it is written [concerning the priestly garments] (Ex. 28, 2) For glory and ornament." (Est. 1, 5) And when these days were completed. Rab and Samuel differ on this point. One said that he was a wise king, and the other, that he was a foolish king. The reason for the statement that he was a wise king, can be derived from the fact that he had made the feast first for the remote subjects, because for his townsmen he could make it at any time; and the other said he was a fool, for he should have made it first for his townsmen, so that should the others rebel, they at least would defend him.

In other words, Achashverosh wanted to show he was a wise king and not an unintelligent leader. Accordingly, he wore those clothes to give him status

Also note the [Kli Yakar](https://www.sefaria.org/Kli_Yakar_on_Exodus.28.39.7?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) who writes on [Shemos 28:39](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.28.39?lang=bi&aliyot=0) the following:

> אמנם אחשורוש חשב להיות נקי מכל אלה, כי אמר אני אשתמש בכלים אלו כדרכן אכילה מרובה משתיה ואז לא אחלל אותם מן קדושתם, **גם בזה נקי אנכי וממלכתי מן הלבשת בגדי כהונה כי דומה כאילו אני עומד ומקריב קרבנות ובזה יהיה נקי גם מן קטרוג כלום הקריב לפניך פר ואיל**...
>
> However, Achashveirosh thought he was clean from all these, because he said I will use these vessels in the way of eating and drinking a lot and then I will not desecrate them from their sanctity. **In this also, I am pure and royal from wearing priestly clothes because it looks as if I am standing and offering sacrifices and in this I will also be pure from being heavenly accused as nothing has been sacrificed before you, a bull or a ram.**

So the Kli Yakar says that Achashveirosh reasoned that he wasn't doing anything wrong as he wasn't offering any sacrifices and it also served to show him in a more regal dress.